# Trying to write a function that takes a name (string) and age to return a greeting

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to write a function that takes a name (string) and age (number) to return a greeting.

```
function createLongGreeting(name, age) {
   if (name === "" && age === number);
   return name, age;
}
```

H`enter code here`ow do I console.log it to the expected result below?

The expected result should be:
Hello, my name is Daniel and I'm 30 years old

Comment: return \`Hello, my name is ${name} and I'm ${age} years old\`? Notice the backticks.

Answer (score 0):

To console log you can try:

```
function createLongGreeting(name, age) {
   return `Hello, my name is ${name} and I'm ${age} years old`;
}
console.log(createLongGreeting('Daniel', 30))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) allow you to insert variables into a string as long as you use backticks to replace the quotes you would normally use with a "normal" string.

But it also looks like you're trying to validate the `name` and `age`. and for that we can use the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator, along with any additional checks you need to make (using `||` - [logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)).

```js
function createLongGreeting(name, age) {

  if (typeof name !== 'string' || name === '') {
    return 'Name must be a non-empty string';
  }
  
  if (typeof age !== 'number' || age <= 0) {
    return 'Age must be a number greater than zero';
  }
  
  return `Hello, my name is ${name} and I'm ${age} years old`;

}

console.log(createLongGreeting('bob', 34));
console.log(createLongGreeting('bob', 'number'));
console.log(createLongGreeting('', 34));
console.log(createLongGreeting('janice', 134));
```